# How to return a specified facet bucket when facet.limit is used in Solr

Tags: solr, filtering, faceted-search

We have a situation where we have a large number of facet buckets for a specific multi-select facet filter, so to make things 'easier' we truncate the returned facet bucket list using `facet.limit`; showing only the top matches, however, if we apply a filter query for a specific value for that facet the bucket and its count can be missing if they are truncated by the `facet.limit`, as the count for that selected facet bucket is lower than for other buckets.

i.e.

```
facet=true
f.category2.facet.mincount=1
f.category2.facet.sort=count
f.category2.facet.limit=4
facet.field={!ex=filter12345}category2
fq={!tag=filter12345}category2:Bottière
```

As the selected `category2` filter value "Bottière" has a low count it is not in the top 4 buckets returned.
Is there a way to *always* return the `category2:Bottière` bucket and count while also truncating the list using `facet.limit`, even if the selcted facet bucket's count is low?

Comment: How about generating a `facet.query` for each `fq` you apply? That way you'll always have separate counts for anything you apply in a filter; it will require a bit of post processing append it to the list (generally, check if the filter value is in the facet list, if not, append it at the end).

Comment: I had hoped there was a way to do this entirely within Solr itself. 
I already considered a pre-processor that would remove `facet.limit` if a filter query exists for that facet, and then truncate the returned list based on `facet.limit` but maintaining the matched bucket in that list.
Not optimal, but I guess I'll follow that path for now.